# Adding Bounce Message back to Mail in Yosemite

Tags: mail.app, applescript, automator

Does anyone have an updated version of [this workflow](http://www.oregontechsupport.com/articles/osx-mail-bounce.php) for adding a Bounce Message feature to Apple Mail in OSX 10.10.3?

Applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
     tell application "Mail"
          repeat with eachMessage in input
               bounce eachMessage
               delete eachMessage
          end repeat
     end tell
end run
```

I've followed the guide but do not receive a bounced email into my inbox when testing as a sender.

[image]

I'm testing this by attempting to send an email from one gmail account to another. Both accounts are Google Apps for Domains accounts.

Comment: What do you mean by “do not see bounce message”? That you have tested the workflow as a **sender**, and have not received such a message (that would indicate the bouncing does not happen)? Or that you are not seeing a message when you bounce as the recipient (that would be expected)?

Comment: the former - see updated question

Comment: Are you certain your email provider or email setup is not silently rejecting or deleting bounce messages (or maybe filing them away as spam)? Also, have you tried running the workflow directly in Automator and looked for error messages?

Comment: I checked spam - nothing in there. Its a Gmail account (google apps for domains so my own domain name). I also tried running the workflow in automator manually. It completes (takes about 30 seconds) but I'm totally new to Automator so not sure how to tell if it has actually worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for that nice Bounce command too, but this is what I found after googling around for a while:

The reason the "bounce" function has been [removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186497/60998) from OS X is because [it does the wrong thing](http://www.dontbouncespam.org/) in the most common use case, which is to try to get spammers to remove you from their mailing list by pretending your email does not exist. The problem is that it's trivial to fake the sender of an email, so bouncing spam usually sends the bounce message to an unsuspecting additional victim; and if the same (innocent!) email address is used to fake the sender for a lot of spam, it would get inundated with bounce messages.

And this is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: I would argue that the people who have allowed their email to be compromised are not "innocent".  They need to be contacted and they need to fix their email.  A bounced email is the way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Apple removed "bounce" from the Mail dictionary.
So "bounce eachMessage" does nothing and the only effect is the message being deleted ("delete eachMessage")

Comment: Where is this documented and when did this happen